# Converting HexEntryID of AppointmentItem returns EwsId which is not equal UniqueId of Appointment object

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

The case is:

1. I am creating an **Appointment** object with EWS. Then save it and get property Id (ItemId type). The value is:

> AAMkAGFmMmI3Y2ZkLWRlNjktNDgyNi1iOTYyLTcyYThhNGI2NjU2MwBGAAAAAAAZkhghCeo1Q6ZG9jEcqo8CBwAYQQne/T3URoAICyAlQqoaAAAAAAENAAAYQQne/T3URoAICyAlQqoaAAAoUZCDAAA=

2. From outlook add-in I'm getting **AppointmnetItem** object which has **EntryId**

> 0000000024A788DE4C8B164294726448FAD7032607005CFD2D234BED54439BEB222BA0522758000000EB36CF00003B52743257E27A4FA6AA876380A189520000D4ABD6530000

3. I'm converting **EntryId** with EWS to EwsId format. This action returns

> AAMkAGFmMmI3Y2ZkLWRlNjktNDgyNi1iOTYyLTcyYThhNGI2NjU2MwBGAAAAAAAkp4jeTIsWQpRyZEj61wMmBwBc/S0jS+1UQ5vrIiugUidYAAAA6zbPAAA7UnQyV+J6T6aqh2OAoYlSAADUq9ZTAAA=

Why EwsId's are different?
(Note: EWS can't bind appointment object by EwsId from point 3)

Comment: What is the error when you try to use the id from #3?

Comment: The error is "The specified object was not found in the store., The store ID provided isn't an ID of an item."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    0003240061663262376366642d646536392d343832362d623936322d373261386134623636353633004600000000001992182109ea3543a646f6311caa8f020700184109defd3dd44680080b202542aa1a00000000010d0000184109defd3dd44680080b202542aa1a0000285190830000

                                                                                          0000000024a788de4c8b164294726448fad7032607005cfd2d234bed54439beb222ba0522758000000eb36cf00003b52743257e27a4fa6aa876380a189520000d4abd6530000

    0003240061663262376366642d646536392d343832362d623936322d3732613861346236363536330046000000000024a788de4c8b164294726448fad7032607005cfd2d234bed54439beb222ba0522758000000eb36cf00003b52743257e27a4fa6aa876380a189520000d4abd6530000
```

So above I've converted you Ids to hex because this is probably the easiest way to explain it. The EWSId contains the PREntryId (along with a bunch of routing information which is documented so you should always use convertId to do the conversation) so you can see that 2,3 is that they are the same for the last portion of the Id. With the Id from 1 the PR_EntryId would be

```
000000001992182109ea3543a646f6311caa8f020700184109defd3dd44680080b202542aa1a00000000010d0000184109defd3dd44680080b202542aa1a0000285190830000
```

and from the providerId in the above  which is documented in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee201952(v=exchg.80).aspx you can tell that those two items in question are in different mailboxes. So it sounds like maybe you may not understand how identifiers work eg the same appointment in two different mailboxes will have two different Identifiers because underlying they are two different objects in the Exchange Store. If your trying to relate items together use the Goid Properties like PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId (just google it for examples and explanations)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yesterday my brain was like a limp bisquit.
I got the first EwsId under User#1 credentials, but the second HexEntryId I got under User#2 credentials. That was a problem. Now ids are the same. Have a good day.